# How can I see a list of all Fitocracy groups?

Tags: fitocracy

I want to see what my options for groups are. Ideally a list sorted by number of members, like http://redditlist.com/. Or is my only option for discovery looking at what groups my friends have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click "[Connect](https://www.fitocracy.com/connect/)" in the top nav bar and you will get a list of all groups. They're alread sorted by number of participants and you can filter them by what you're interested in.